# Find Font size of text to draw on image from text box

Tags: wpf

I am currently working POC in WPF for inserting text over the image. An image is displayed in a view box. When the user wants to insert the text over the image textbox will appear with font details selection combo box. After entering the text and font details when save button is clicked same text should be drawn over the image with same font details. But currently, the font size of the text is reduced.

Please let me know how to find the font size of text to draw on the image.

Comment: Some [mcve] of the problem would be nice. Can you please add that so we don't have to guess what your app looks like?

Answer (score -1):

> But currently font size of the text is reduced

Don't forget that the viewbox performs a zoom. Maybe you should try to retrive the viewbox zoom factor and multiply it to the textbox font size to have the real displayed size of your text on the screen.